# 25 HTML fields - different fields for different user level?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, http-post

So I have 25 HTML fields (Text, Drop downs, Selects etc...)
I would need these to show to user depending on their level, some may show some may not, so far only option I've came up with is using if statements to check for user level before loading field, example:

```
if(userLevel == 1 || userLevel == 2){
echo("<input type='text' name='phoneNumber'/>");
```

But after I do that the code ends up very long and messy, is there any way to give each field some kind of ID and on page load, based on users level load those fields with specific ID's?

Same for JS field validation, anyway to give each field id (like email, url) so it gets validated automatically rather than writing and calling onChange on each field?

Comment: "is there any way to give each field some kind of ID and on page load, based on users level load those fields with specific ID's?" -- I believe then also you have to check the condition for user level and call necessary block of code.

Comment: yeah i *hate* building html forms for this reason, so tedious.  i also like to return the fields w php `value="<?php if(isset($phone)){echo $phone;}?>"` in case the user misses something they don't have to retype everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways.

For a quick solution you can use an array and a for cycle, e.g.:

```
function dumpForm($userLevel) {
    $fields = array(                                                                                                                                                   
        'name'      => array(
            'type'  => 'text',
            'level' => 2,
            'value' => ''
        ),
        'phone'     => array(
            'type'  => 'text',
            'level' => 1,
            'value' => ''
        ),
        'email'     => array(
            'type'  => 'text',
            'level' => 1,
            'value' => 'email@example.org'
        )
    );

    foreach ($fields as $name => $data) {
        extract($data);
        if ($level <= $userLevel)
            echo "<input type='$type' name='$name' value='$value'/>\n";
    }
}

echo "\nForm (level 1):\n";
dumpForm(1);

echo "\nForm (level 2):\n";
dumpForm(2);
```

You can also add an additional field to the array for javascript validation, or add some logic based on the `type` field (e.g. when type is `number` generate a `text` entry with number validation).